# How to buy & use train tickets from Algés to Lisbon

Tags: trains, tickets, lisbon

A [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70811/where-to-buy-top-up-public-transport-tickets-in-lisbon) was asked 3 years ago for inner city transport cards, but this is for a different route, not using a transport card, and I am looking for more up to date answers.

I'm going to Lisbon next week and will be staying outside of the city in Algés. There are several buses and trains we can use to get into the city, but the sites I can find are unclear as to how to buy tickets.

Rome2Rio mentions buying tickets at the station, but others mention many stations don't have ticket counters. For buses I presume I can buy onboard. We would probably only go into the city 2 or 3 times, and walk whilst there so the transport card doesn't seem worth it.

As well as how to buy, how are these tickets used, are they one journey from A to B, do they have zones, do we scan them as we board etc.

So, where in Algés can we buy these tickets, and how are they used?

Comment: According to [Comboios de Portugal](https://www.cp.pt/passageiros/en/train-times/Stations/alges-station), there is ticket vending machines. You can also buy tickets online if you wish. When i buy single tickets, I normally do it online and you can just use your phone or print the ticket and show them to the audit guy. Can't give a full answer though as I believe it's more complicated than what I'm saying here.

Comment: Related question, might interest you: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/143903/buying-train-tickets-in-portugal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after coming back from the trip I thought I would update.

As well as ticket desks, there are also a long row of ticket machines at Alges station, to ensure tickets can be bought 24/7. Tickets can be purchased from those machines, and must be put through the barrier to gain access to the platform of the station. Different types of ticket are available, and you should keep them until after you disembark the train.